# BROUTING's target "redirect" in ebtables behaving in a strange way

Tags: iptables, bridge

### Situation

```
(host A)-------(bridge B)------(host C)
```

where:

- A has `MAC A` on it's interface
- C has `MAC C` on it's interface
- B has `MAC BA` and `MAC BC` on it's two interfaces (depending on who it's facing)
- B has `MAC BB` for it's bridge

the bridge bridges it's two interfaces together, and [ebtables](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net) and iptables are used for filtering.

If I set my only ebtables rule to redirect all IPv4-containing frames to L3 filtering:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPV4 -i eth1 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
```

then, if I send a frame from A to C containing IPv4, I am supposed to get the destination MAC address to be the one of the bridge interface (`MAC BA`) when I start L3 filtering if I believe the documentation.

```
redirect
   The  redirect  target will change the MAC target address to that of the bridge device the frame arrived on. This target can only be used in the
   BROUTING chain of the broute table and the PREROUTING chain of the nat table.  In the BROUTING chain, the MAC address of  the  bridge  port  is
   used as destination address, in the PREROUTING chain, the MAC address of the bridge is used.

   --redirect-target target
          Specifies  the standard target. After doing the MAC redirect, the rule still has to give a standard target so ebtables knows what to do.
          The default target is ACCEPT. Making it CONTINUE could let you use multiple target extensions on the same frame. Making it DROP  in  the
          BROUTING chain will let the frames be routed. RETURN is also allowed. Note that using RETURN in a base chain is not allowed.
```

### Observation

When I set up iptables to log incoming packets:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix "ip_raw_prerouting: " --log-level debug
```

I can see that iptables get frames with `MAC BA` as source and `MAC A` as destination instead of what I expected (`MAC A` as — unchanged — source and `MAC BA` as new destination)

### log info

- `MAC A` = `08:00:27:17:49:6d`
- `MAC C` = `08:00:27:d5:24:36`
- `MAC BA` = `08:00:27:d8:32:61`

On the bridge:

`kern.log`

```
Aug 19 17:51:05 spy kernel: [20963.557665] br_br IN=eth1 OUT= MAC source = 08:00:27:17:49:6d MAC dest = 08:00:27:d5:24:36 proto = 0x0800
Aug 19 17:51:05 spy kernel: [20963.557701] ip_raw_pre: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=08:00:27:d8:32:61:08:00:27:17:49:6d:08:00 SRC=192.168.142.254 DST=192.168.142.103 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55401 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46721 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

`# ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:df:b7:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d8:32:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 08:00:27:d8:32:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### Question

Any idea what that could be? any additional information welcome!

other tags (I don't have enough rep here): ebtables, netfilter, brouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all actually normal.

On the log, MAC=08:00:27:d8:32:61:08:00:27:17:49:6d:08:00 is actually destMAC:sourceMAC:proto